# MySQL Get Max ID of result UNLESS a value in a column equals 1

Tags: mysql

I know how to get the Max ID.  That's easy.  But I have a situation where the MaxID COULD be the row that has a value of 1.  Example.. I have the following tables:

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE people (
    id INT NOT NULL
    ,NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO people (id, NAME) VALUES (1, 'tony');
INSERT INTO people (id, NAME) VALUES (2, 'dave');
INSERT INTO people (id, NAME) VALUES (3, 'dan');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE orders (
    id INT NOT NULL
    ,peopleid INT NOT NULL
    ,VALUE INT
);

INSERT INTO orders (id, peopleid, VALUE) VALUES (1, 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO orders (id, peopleid, VALUE) VALUES (2, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO orders (id, peopleid, VALUE) VALUES (3, 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO orders (id, peopleid, VALUE) VALUES (4, 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO orders (id, peopleid, VALUE) VALUES (5, 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO orders (id, peopleid, VALUE) VALUES (6, 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO orders (id, peopleid, VALUE) VALUES (7, 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO orders (id, peopleid, VALUE) VALUES (8, 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO orders (id, peopleid, VALUE) VALUES (9, 2, NULL);
```

which when I run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM people AS p
    LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.peopleid = p.id
```

I get the result:

```
id  name  id  peopleid  value
1   tony  1   1         null
1   tony  2   1         1
1   tony  3   1         null
1   tony  8   1         null
2   dave  4   2         null
2   dave  5   2         null
2   dave  6   2         null
2   dave  7   2         null
2   dave  9   2         null
3   dan   null null     null
```

I need the result

```
id  name  id  peopleid  value
1   tony  2   1         1
2   dave  9   2         null
3   dan   null null     null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT id FROM tablename
 ORDER BY value=1 DESC, id DESC
 LIMIT 1;


 SELECT persons.personid,persons.name,othertable.id
 FROM persons
 LEFT JOIN othertable 
    ON othertable.personid = persons.personid
 LEFT JOIN othertable check
    ON check.personid = persons.personid
    ON  check.id > othertable.id
    AND (othertable.value!=1 OR check.value=1)
 WHERE check.personid IS NULL;
```

Final:

```
SELECT people.id,people.NAME,orders.id,orders.VALUE
FROM people
LEFT JOIN orders 
  ON orders.peopleid = people.id
LEFT JOIN orders checkbigger
  ON  checkbigger.peopleid = people.id
  AND (
    (
      checkbigger.id > orders.id
      AND orders.value <=> checkbigger.value
    )
    OR
    (
      orders.value IS NULL AND checkbigger.value IS NOT NULL
    )
  )
WHERE checkbigger.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I'm using this table as a join, so I can't do the limit 1.

Comment: Add your actual query to you question then, and we'll see whether we can get it in the join or whether we need a subquery.

Comment: okay.. I updated the question with the 2 tables..  I'd put in the query.. but it would be wrong..  obviously why I'm adding the question.. haha

Comment: Well, even a wrong query most likely clearly shows the intentions. I cobbled some (untested!) query together which probably does what you want.

Comment: Okay.. I've add the tables and a very basic query.  Your example wouldn't work for me, because it needs to be a LEFT JOIN outright..  I'm sorry for not posting this at first..

Comment: @DanManina: OK, I added a query that works with your data here (not using temporary tables).

Answer (score 1):

This will work without using `LIMIT`. If there are no `value = 1` rows, the first `MAX` will be null so the `COALESCE` returns the second `MAX`. If there are `value = 1` rows, the first `MAX` will be non-null so it gets returned.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(
    MAX(CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN id END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN id END))
FROM a
```